# Ubuntu 9.10 PATH var/lib/gems/1.8 no such file or dir

Tags: path, rubygems, ubuntu-9.10

I'm  using ubuntu 9.10 and i cant see gems located in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems , so i cant execute gems like rake for rails. When I write $PATH in the console I get:

bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/dombesz/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin: No such file or directory

I also tried to add to ~/.bashrc , export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin

When I write gem list --local, shows only the gems located at ~/.gems dir.

This problem started when I installed rubygems from source.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does gem -v return? What about "which gem"? When you rolled from source did you run "make install" with sudo?

Comment: if you just want to look at $PATH you should type "echo $PATH" (without the quotes), this should prevent the error you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a path problem, so i deleted all the installations and reinstalled and added paths, now i still have the no such file or directory error when i look at $PATH, but everything works.